# Wordpress $_GET['post'] in admin returns NULL

Tags: php, wordpress, get

I want to modify a custom field in my WordPress edit post page and I will need the post ID to do this. I have a function in functions.php and it works fine when I manually enter the post ID. The issue comes up when I try getting the post ID from the URL but the $_GET['post'] is proving to be useless. `var_dump($_GET['post']) returns NULL`, `$global $post; var_dump($post->ID) returns NULL`. The URL is the normal post edit link

URL: http://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=435&action=edit

I have been able to get the post ID via the admin_head hook but can't get it to work in my other function suing set_query_var(). Have a look below at my modified code:

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'get_post_ID' );
function get_post_ID() {
global $post;
$thePostID = 0;
$pagenow = isset($GLOBALS['pagenow']) ? $GLOBALS['pagenow'] : null;
if ( $pagenow == 'post.php' ) {
    $thePostID = $post->ID;
    set_query_var('my_post_id', $thePostID);
}
return $post->ID;
}

function get_admin_post_ID() {
    var_dump(get_query_var('my_post_id'));
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'get_admin_post_ID' );
```

What could be the issue here? Is there something I am missing? Kindly assist.

Comment: Do you see `?post=xxx` in the URL when it doesn't work? Have you tried using hooks/actions to get and manipulate the data? The question is a bit unclear at the moment.

Comment: It would help to see url example of what you see. Please add it to your question.

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen I have edited the question to add the link

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have placed the code in a filter

Comment: Please show us all relevant code and the complete URL you're accessing.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, there you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what $_GET return instead?
Are you using some plugin that edit posts, and that do not use/pass this var?
As said before, the browser address url, return something like this or not?
`https://subdomain.w3host.com/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?post=100&action=edit`

PS: *var_dump* that return NULL on $_GET['post'], simply mean that there is so, a php
*Notice: Undefined index:*
the *post* var do not exist

Comment: Yes, that is the browser URL. I have modified the question to add it. I have even tried it with all plugins deactivated and with the WP 2020 theme

Comment: really strange: if i put this into any plugin, at top of any instruction, var_dump $_GET['post'] return me correctly: string(3) "110" . The unique reason of your problem, should be that somewhere, earlier on code, something like this fire: unset($_GET['post']); then when you try to get it, it result undefined and return null into var_dump

Comment: I do not have any other code that touches on the $_GET. I had the issue on an existing site and created a new installation with no plugin and the result is the same!

Comment: OK, sooo strange! What happen if you open file /wp-admin/post.php then on the very top of the file, just after the starting <?php tag, you put this? print_r($_GET['post']);exit;   ... then click into -> Edit post

Comment: I'm sorry to do not have a valid answer for this, except the said above: or an unset($_GET) happen right before into your function or your code, or it seem to me to be impossible that you get an undefined var. May wordpress nullify the $_GET for some reason, and if the post to be edited display, it is not a server related issue (assuming that an empty $_GET is possible that can be caused by a server issue, that i do not think so): this could help maybe, if not already seen, especially the last answer? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46108/wordpress-and-get-params

Comment: Thanks for the help. There was something unsetting the $_GET thus the NULL return value.